# get pointer to sub array in 4 dimensional array

Tags: c

I have declared a 4 dimensional array : `int board[3][3][3][3]`

How can I get a pointer to the sub array, for example I tried something like this :

```
int sub_board[3][3] = board[1][2];
```

but it didn't work and I couldn't find any way to get a pointer to the sub array.

Comment: Do you *really* need to use a 4D array?

Comment: Sorry to be the naysayer, but don't you think this post lacks a little on _showing efforts_ part?

Comment: An array is not a pointer. That's why you get error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get a *pointer* to a sub array:

```
int (*sub_board)[3][3] = &board[1][2];
```

`sub_board` points to a sub array with known dimensions, but its elements must be dereferenced as `(*sub_board)[i][j]`.

Alternately, you can use a pointer to the beginning of the sub array, but without an embedded notion of the number of elements:

```
int (*sub_array)[3] = board[1][2];
```

The elements are more intuitively accessed as `sub_array[i][j]`, but the range for `i` cannot be statically checked at compile time.

Here is an illustration of how these work. For clarity, I have used different sizes for the different dimensions:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int board[2][3][4][5];
    int (*sub_board)[4][5] = &board[1][2];
    int (*sub_array)[5] = board[1][2];
    int n = 0;

    for (int i0 = 0; i0 < 2; i0++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 5; i3++) {
                    board[i0][i1][i2][i3] = n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("board = %p\n", (void*)board);
    printf("sub array board[1][2] should be at offset 1 * 3 * 4 * 5 + 2 * 4 * 5 = %d\n",
           1 * 3 * 4 * 5 + 2 * 4 * 5);
    printf("sub_board = %p\n", (void*)sub_board);
    printf("offset    = %lld\n", (long long int)(((intptr_t)sub_board - (intptr_t)board) / (int)sizeof(int)));
    printf("sub_array = %p\n", (void*)sub_board);
    printf("offset    = %lld\n", (long long int)(((intptr_t)sub_array - (intptr_t)board) / (int)sizeof(int)));

    printf("addressing using board:\n");
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 5; i3++) {
            printf("%8d", board[1][2][i2][i3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("addressing using sub_board:\n");
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 5; i3++) {
            printf("%8d", (*sub_board)[i2][i3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("addressing using sub_array:\n");
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 5; i3++) {
            printf("%8d", sub_array[i2][i3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For `int board[3][5][7][9];
    int (*sub_board1)[7][9] = board[1][2];` I get: "*warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type*"

Comment: Most usable would be `int (*sub_board)[3] = board[1][2]`. For your type, you have to add the address-operator to the RHS of the assignment.

Comment: @Olaf: I rephrased my answer to clarify the different options.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **copy** the sub-array

```
int sub[3][3];
memcpy(sub, board[1][2], sizeof sub);
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax should be:

```
int (*sub_board)[3] = board[1][2];
```

Comment: The OP want the sub-array, not the sub-array of the sub-array.

Comment: Actually, it is not 100% clear from the question what OP wants. This answer provides a pointer to be used with two additional indexes, for ex.  `int xx = sub_board[3][2];`.